# Find median in nth range in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to find **value of every median** in my dataset for every **15 days**. Dataset has three columns - index, value and date.

This is for evaluation of this median according to some conditions. Each of 15 days will get new value according to conditions. 
I've tried several approaches (mostly python comprehension) but I am still a beginner to solve it properly.

```
    value   date        index
14  13065   1983-07-15  14
15  13065   1983-07-16  15
16  13065   1983-07-17  16
17  13065   1983-07-18  17
18  13065   1983-07-19  18
19  13065   1983-07-20  19
20  13065   1983-07-21  20
21  13065   1983-07-22  21
22  13065   1983-07-23  22
23  .....    .........  .. 

medians = [dataset['value'].median() for range(0, len(dataset['index']), 15) in dataset['value']]
```

I am expecting to return medians from the dataframe to a new variable.

```
syntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Comment: Can you also show the dataframe. Just a dummy dataframe

Comment: Ok I will put the dataframe in original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have data in the below format:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start = '2016/02/12', periods = 1000, freq='1D'),
                                         'value': np.random.randint(1,1000,1000)})
test.head()

    date       value
0   2016-02-12  243
1   2016-02-13  313
2   2016-02-14  457
3   2016-02-15  236
4   2016-02-16  893
```

If you want to median for every 15 days then use [pd.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) and [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `date:`

```
test.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15D', key='date')).median().reset_index()

date        Value
2016-02-12  457.0
2016-02-27  733.0
2016-03-13  688.0
2016-03-28  504.0
2016-04-12  591.0
```

Note that while using pd.Grouper, your date column should be of type datetime. If it's not, convert using:

```
test['date'] = pd.to_datetime(test['date'])
```

Comment: Okey It is helpful, I made progress but values are little bit strange now. E.g. - 0.000000e+00  or 9.100000e-02. Can I use groupby and Grouper on my index column?

Comment: If median is the name of your column then you can use:  `df['median']=df['median'].map('${:,.2f}'.format)` to round off to two decimals.

Comment: What do you plan to achieve by grouping on index column?

Comment: Well values are different. Also in your column -> original: 2016-02-12  243 after: 2016-02-12  457.0. Sorry, Are you not applying median on date column not value column? Thank you!

Comment: It means that from 2016-02-12 to 2016-02-26 median is 457. The median is taken from Value column.

Comment: Ah I get it. It is confusing from the beginning. Firstly, I was expecting the real date for median. thx

Comment: @jezrae Not also from my side

Comment: Btw what will be the syntax if I would like to find the middle value not median. Something like this doesn't work
`RSDF5 = RSDF4.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15D', key='DATE')).[int(len(RSDF5)//2)].reset_index()`